# Plot fill_between with pandas time series. ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to replicate an extremely simple example from here: https://python-graph-gallery.com/241-improve-area-chart/

My data.

Values:

```
x = newgraph['values'].values

[141.65166667 117.97286957 130.14766667 130.444      127.9445
 178.01919048 117.025       77.90055556 119.11394444 357.88333333
 161.099       61.46366667 126.849      142.43683333 101.7946875
 141.2142     292.74857143 102.59154167  85.747125    83.22307692
 117.77190909 150.75015789 275.282      148.58395833 110.0824
  93.09858824 131.0881      73.98646154  69.183       99.2175
  84.78016667 157.7805     171.10766667 170.10535714 140.21433333
 257.95166667 142.49668    120.20757143 115.42713913 138.1566
 168.06071429 237.249      154.69242857 145.43288889 155.80169231
 114.72075     72.18833333 160.4758      93.703       68.94159259
 125.05733333 211.1284     129.60669231  81.67755     84.8684
  85.923      102.71911364 110.54144     86.9905     138.85572222
 146.96868    161.422      194.9203      84.93763636 155.35046667
 123.97671429 133.49786667 134.605825   185.846      106.16564706
 253.186       73.02047059 131.13469565  75.63633333 167.81266667
  83.67825926  99.68016667 147.33016667  90.34742857 134.986
 131.1215     181.683       89.59085714  68.14153846  83.3042069 ]
```

Date index:

```
y = newgraph['values'].index

DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05',
               '2020-01-06', '2020-01-07', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-09',
               '2020-01-10', '2020-01-11', '2020-01-12', '2020-01-13',
               '2020-01-14', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-16', '2020-01-17',
               '2020-01-18', '2020-01-20', '2020-01-21', '2020-01-22',
               '2020-01-23', '2020-01-24', '2020-01-25', '2020-01-27',
               '2020-01-28', '2020-01-29', '2020-01-30', '2020-01-31',
               '2020-02-01', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-03', '2020-02-04',
               '2020-02-05', '2020-02-06', '2020-02-07', '2020-02-08',
               '2020-02-10', '2020-02-11', '2020-02-12', '2020-02-13',
               '2020-02-14', '2020-02-16', '2020-02-17', '2020-02-18',
               '2020-02-19', '2020-02-20', '2020-02-21', '2020-02-22',
               '2020-02-23', '2020-02-24', '2020-02-25', '2020-02-26',
               '2020-02-27', '2020-02-28', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-01',
               '2020-03-02', '2020-03-03', '2020-03-04', '2020-03-05',
               '2020-03-06', '2020-03-07', '2020-03-09', '2020-03-10',
               '2020-03-11', '2020-03-12', '2020-03-13', '2020-03-14',
               '2020-03-15', '2020-03-16', '2020-03-17', '2020-03-18',
               '2020-03-19', '2020-03-20', '2020-03-21', '2020-03-23',
               '2020-03-24', '2020-03-25', '2020-03-26', '2020-03-27',
               '2020-03-28', '2020-03-29', '2020-03-30', '2020-03-31',
               '2020-04-08'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='local_date', freq=None)
```

My attempt to try out the tutorial:

```
plt.fill_between( x, y, color="skyblue", alpha=0.4)
plt.show()

ValueError: view limit minimum -36876.15 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

Is there a way to fill in under the line in a time series? Or does this only work for numbers on the y axis?

I'm just trying to replicate those stock market graphs where there's a pleasing shade under the time series line.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your import / your data. X is missing the comma between the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Imports

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

### Fix the data

#### Values

- With the provided data, make a `str`, separated the values by a space and then filtered out the blanks to create a list.

```py
values = "141.65166667 117.97286957 130.14766667 130.444      127.9445 \
178.01919048 117.025       77.90055556 119.11394444 357.88333333 \
 161.099       61.46366667 126.849      142.43683333 101.7946875 \
 141.2142     292.74857143 102.59154167  85.747125    83.22307692 \
 117.77190909 150.75015789 275.282      148.58395833 110.0824 \
  93.09858824 131.0881      73.98646154  69.183       99.2175 \
  84.78016667 157.7805     171.10766667 170.10535714 140.21433333 \
 257.95166667 142.49668    120.20757143 115.42713913 138.1566 \
 168.06071429 237.249      154.69242857 145.43288889 155.80169231 \
 114.72075     72.18833333 160.4758      93.703       68.94159259 \
 125.05733333 211.1284     129.60669231  81.67755     84.8684 \
  85.923      102.71911364 110.54144     86.9905     138.85572222 \
 146.96868    161.422      194.9203      84.93763636 155.35046667 \
 123.97671429 133.49786667 134.605825   185.846      106.16564706 \
 253.186       73.02047059 131.13469565  75.63633333 167.81266667 \
  83.67825926  99.68016667 147.33016667  90.34742857 134.986 \
 131.1215     181.683       89.59085714  68.14153846  83.3042069"

values = values.split(' ')
values = list(filter(lambda x: x != "", values))
print(values[:5])

>>> ['141.65166667', '117.97286957', '130.14766667', '130.444', '127.9445']
```

#### Dates

```py
dates = ['2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05',
               '2020-01-06', '2020-01-07', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-09',
               '2020-01-10', '2020-01-11', '2020-01-12', '2020-01-13',
               '2020-01-14', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-16', '2020-01-17',
               '2020-01-18', '2020-01-20', '2020-01-21', '2020-01-22',
               '2020-01-23', '2020-01-24', '2020-01-25', '2020-01-27',
               '2020-01-28', '2020-01-29', '2020-01-30', '2020-01-31',
               '2020-02-01', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-03', '2020-02-04',
               '2020-02-05', '2020-02-06', '2020-02-07', '2020-02-08',
               '2020-02-10', '2020-02-11', '2020-02-12', '2020-02-13',
               '2020-02-14', '2020-02-16', '2020-02-17', '2020-02-18',
               '2020-02-19', '2020-02-20', '2020-02-21', '2020-02-22',
               '2020-02-23', '2020-02-24', '2020-02-25', '2020-02-26',
               '2020-02-27', '2020-02-28', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-01',
               '2020-03-02', '2020-03-03', '2020-03-04', '2020-03-05',
               '2020-03-06', '2020-03-07', '2020-03-09', '2020-03-10',
               '2020-03-11', '2020-03-12', '2020-03-13', '2020-03-14',
               '2020-03-15', '2020-03-16', '2020-03-17', '2020-03-18',
               '2020-03-19', '2020-03-20', '2020-03-21', '2020-03-23',
               '2020-03-24', '2020-03-25', '2020-03-26', '2020-03-27',
               '2020-03-28', '2020-03-29', '2020-03-30', '2020-03-31',
               '2020-04-08']
```

#### DataFrame

```py
# combine dates and values
data = list(zip(dates, values))

# create the DateFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'value'])

# convert date to datetime and value to float
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['value'] = df['value'].astype('float')
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 85 entries, 0 to 84
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   date    85 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 1   value   85 non-null     float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1)

# df.head()

      date       value
2020-01-02  141.651667
2020-01-03  117.972870
2020-01-04  130.147667
2020-01-05  130.444000
2020-01-06  127.944500
```

### Plot

```py
plt.fill_between(df['date'], df['value'], color="skyblue", alpha=0.4)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

[image]